# Splitting string from file

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string to load from a file:

```
JC 10D 6S 7S 7C 9H 8C KC 2H
```

I use scanner's `scan.next()` for this so that I only get one expression each time.

How do I split these expressions into strings?

For example JC into "J" and "C".

I tried doing charAt(), but I realized that it there might be trouble splitting 10D into "10" and "D" since I'm just reading it from a file.
Should I try to use String.split()? However, I don't know how to use regex, so the implementation would have to be simple.
Thanks!

Comment: What's the criteria that make you split `"10D"` into `{"10", "D"}`, not  `{"1", "0", "D"}`

Comment: It's actually data for cards. 10D means 10 Diamond, JC Jack Club.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's actually data for cards. 10D means 10 Diamond, JC Jack Club.

Since you know that you'll get two parts, you can do it with two calls os [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method:

- The first call makes a substring for the initial `length()-1` letters
- The second call makes a substring for the last letter

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/pJEEBk)

```
String card = "10D";
String rank = card.substring(0, card.length()-1);
String suit = card.substring(card.length()-1);
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex you can do this :

```
       String s = "JC";
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
       Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
       if(m.find()) {
         System.out.println("Rank :"+m.group());
         System.out.println("Suit :"+s.substring(m.end()));
       } else {

           System.out.println("Rank :"+s.substring(0,1));
           System.out.println("Suit :"+s.substring(1));   
       }
```